# NameError("name 'engine' is not defined",) while running using pd_writer method in snowflake-connector

Tags: python, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

```
"""Module for acquiring Raw blast Data"""
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import sys
import pandas
import pytz
from datetime import datetime,date
import snowflake
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
import boto3


    def sf_To_df(self):
        sf_data = self.salesForceAuth.query_all(self.queryColumns)
        sf_data=dict(sf_data)
        try:            
            cursor=snowflake.connector.connect(user=snowflake_user_path,password=snowflake_secret_path,account=snowflake_account,warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,database=snowflake_database,schema=snowflake_schema);

            for dictKey1, dictValue1 in sf_data.items():
                if dictKey1 == "records":
                    sf_Df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(dictValue1)
                    **sf_Df.to_sql(dictKey1, engine, index=False, method=pd_writer)**
            
        except Exception as e:
            typ, obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
            print("exception while reading the key value: ", e.__repr__(),tb.tb_lineno)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The engine is your connection

```
def sf_To_df(self):
    sf_data = self.salesForceAuth.query_all(self.queryColumns)
    sf_data=dict(sf_data)
    try:            
        cursor=snowflake.connector.connect(user=snowflake_user_path,password=snowflake_secret_path,account=snowflake_account,warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,database=snowflake_database,schema=snowflake_schema);

    for dictKey1, dictValue1 in sf_data.items():
        if dictKey1 == "records":
            sf_Df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(dictValue1)
            **sf_Df.to_sql(dictKey1, cursor, index=False, method=pd_writer)**
    
except Exception as e:
    typ, obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print("exception while reading the key value: ", e.__repr__(),tb.tb_lineno)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. After doing so I am able to resolve "NameError(“name 'engine' is not defined”,) " error but I started this error. Any clue on what is going wrong:

DatabaseError("Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting",)

Comment: you are missing an argument, but for that you must debug it